# How to call over-ridden abstract class methods

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have scenario like

Here is the abstract class

```
    abstract class A
    {
            public void add()
            {
                    //do something
            }
    }
```

Here is the class that extends above abstract class

```
    class B extends A
    {
            @Override
            public void add()
            {
                    //do something else
            }
    }
```

Here is the class in which I want to call both the add methods

```
    class C
    {
            A a = new B();

            // Calls B's add method

            a.add();

            // Call A's add method ???
    }
```

How to call A's add method???

Comment: See this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Comment: Call super.add() inside Class B's add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained above by various people, you can't. If we try and understand as to what you want to achieve, i guess what you need is an interface and two classes.

```
interface AddInterface {
 public void add();
}

class A implements AddInterface {
//your abstract class' version of add goes here
}

class B implements AddInterface {
//your other add definition.
}
```

You end up replacing references to `A` with AddInterface.
Again, it all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. That's the whole point of polymorphism and encapsulation - you've created an instance of `B`, so `B` gets to decide what `add` means. Maybe `B` is trying to enforce some business rules about when you can call `add` for example - it would be useless if you could bypass those rules and call `A.add()` directly on an instance of `B`. The implementation of `B.add()` can decide when and whether to call `super.add()`, but code *outside* `B` doesn't get to make that decision.

Comment: "You can't" is very defeatist -- C++ also has polymorphism, but there you can happily say `b.A::add()` if you prefer to call the base class's implementation (even if `A::add()` is pure-virtual)... :-) I guess a more appropriate wording would be that "Java decided by design and for your comfort to not expose you to any unnecessary choices."

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't see it as defeatism, but as not being broken like C++ is. It's a good thing not to be able to do it, so it's more optimistic than defeatist.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's not a matter of "unnecessary choices" - it's a matter of breaking polymorphism. Do you disagree with the *accuracy* of "you can't"? Just because you can do something dangerous in another language doesn't mean you can do so *or should be able to do so* in another language.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, it's a matter of opinion and design... I could also argue that the user may be fully aware that she has a derived object and would like to be able to use that extra information. I'm not convinced that that "breaks" anything -- after all, the simplest syntax does always get you the "expected" behaviour, and any other behaviour would be visible immediately in the syntax. So...yeah, calling the base implementation is a choice that Java decides not to offer to users of the derived class.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It breaks the ability of a class to reason about its internal state and keep it consistent. That feels like a pretty big breakage to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because it would break polymorphism. If B overrides A's `add` method, it's because it **must** add in another way to satify its contract. Not doing it the way it needs to would break B's invariants, and probably also A's invariants.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `super`.

```
class B extends A
{
        //over ride method
        public add()
        {
                super.add();
                //do something else
        }
}
```

Comment: but super will only work in `this`-Context (So you can't use `a.super.add()` in order to call `A.add()`)

Comment: @PhilippWendt: Oh, absolutely - hence my example of including it in B's `add()`

Answer (score 1):

```
class B extends A
{
//over ride method
public add()
{
    //do something else
}

public add2()
{
    super.add();
}
}


class C {
A a = new B();

// Calls B's add method
a.add();

// Call A's add method
a.add2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got what i want but in different way here it is how ---

```
    class D extends A
    {
            public add()
            {
                    //Log here..........
                    super.add();
            }
    }
```

This will help me not to force B to call default implementation of A by avoiding super.add();

As we have over-ridden it to change functionality.

```
    class C
    {
            A a = new B();
            // Call B's Add method
            a.add();

            a = new D();
            // Call A's Add method via D
            a.add();
    }
```

I think there is no other better way than this :)